# How to use module in kotlin Mutliplatform moblie

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

Hey I am learning Kotlin Multiplatform mobile. I starting learning from the [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kmm-integrate-in-existing-app.html#create-a-shared-module-for-cross-platform-code). I successfully run the module in android and ios platform, without any problem. Now I want to implement this in real project. I successfully created the module inside my pre-existing android directory. According to this [Make your cross-platform application work on iOS](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kmm-integrate-in-existing-app.html#make-your-cross-platform-application-work-on-ios) we can only use module inside the android directory. I work as android developer and my other team have ios developer. So the problem is we have different system for android and ios. So how can I share this module to the Ios team. Please guide me how to achieve this. I read somewhere ios need [XCFramework](https://github.com/ge-org/multiplatform-swiftpackage). But I am not sure, how can I achieved this. Can someone guide me step wise? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile provides you with an ability to build frameworks for iOS. It can be delivered in several ways:

- Simple ModuleName.framework file ready to be imported into your teammate's app,
- [CocoaPods integration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-cocoapods.html), providing your teammate with the ability to rebuild this framework from sources and to use third-party libraries from Kotlin code,
- [Universal (fat) framework](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-build-native-binaries.html#build-universal-frameworks) and [XCFramework](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-build-native-binaries.html#build-xcframeworks). These two are designed to provide the framework user with the ability to build the result app for different CPU architectures. This would be helpful when publishing the app.

If your aim is to just show the iOS team an example of Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile power, I think it would be enough to [declare the framework](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-build-native-binaries.html#declare-binaries), build it by executing the appropriate gradle task and share the result file.

If they would also like to put some code into the iOS-specific part of your module, adding the CocoaPods integration will be a good idea.

Comment: great answer. Yes I want to start working KMM in my both platform. So `CocoaPods integration` and `XCFramework` can we use both? Because I don;t know about differernt CPU architectures? or only CocoaPods works in different architectures as well?

Comment: XCFramework would be useful only for the actual publication of the result app into the App Store. Using CocoaPods will also let you build for all supported iOS targets([see this link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-supported-platforms.html)) but it will create non-universal frameworks and require rebuilding when you build your iOS app for another target. Usually it appears when you swap between a simulator and a real device.

Comment: got it thanks a million